# analyze the subtracted histogram of two images using matlab to find the difference at each point in amplitude

Tags: image, matlab, processing, digital

I have two grayscale images of same pixel and size of material at different voltages. I have to compare them using histograms in matlab to find difference of all pixel values at different bins means all sample points. Beacause I need to check the max diff and min diff so that I could find the min and max vibration. I can find histogram of different images. and also i can find histogram of subtracted image. But how to analyze subtracted image to get the compared data.Please help with proper matlab code

Edit:
What OP has tried so far:

```
%two histograms in one fig
image1 = imread('0_25_1.jpg'); % Image 1
image2 = imread('0_35_1.jpg'); % Image 2

figure
subplot(2,2,1);
imhist(image1);
subplot(2,2,2);
imhist(image2);
subplot(2,2,3);
imhist(image1-image2);

%second one is.....
image1 = imread('0_25_1.jpg'); % Image 1
image2 = imread('0_35_1.jpg'); % Image 2
[counts,x] = imhist(image1);
stem(counts,x,'b');
hold on
[counts,x] = imhist(image2);
stem(counts,x,'r')
hold off
```

Comment: We aren't a code writing service.  You show us what you have tried, and we help you solve your problem.  Asking us for code is not the way it works here.  Read this informative guide on how to ask the proper question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried two codes...%two histograms in one fig
image1 = imread('0_25_1.jpg'); % Image 1
image2 = imread('0_35_1.jpg'); % Image 2
figure, subplot(2,2,1); imhist(image1); subplot(2,2,2); imhist(image2);subplot(2,2,3);imhist(image1-image2); second one is.....image1 = imread('0_25_1.jpg'); % Image 1
image2 = imread('0_35_1.jpg'); % Image 2
[counts,x] = imhist(image1)
stem(counts,x,'b')
hold on
[counts,x] = imhist(image2)  stem(counts,x,'r')...How to get information about pixels distribution at all intensity levels(256)

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the minimum and maximum differences?

```
[maxVal, maxLocation] = max(image1(:)-image2(:));
[minVal, minLocation] = min(image1(:)-image2(:));
```

Comment: Thanx @user1543042...but i need Minimum Pixel distribution and max pixel distribution in subtracted histogram. Also At which point it is (from 0 to 255)